# Excel 2013 VBA Workbooks.Open Loses Debug Step Mode?

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

When I step into a sub and then step into the statement:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\file2"
```

it seems like the file opens okay but on return the remainder of the calling sub just executes (I lose step into mode). Can this be helped?

Comment: Could please post the rest of the sub's code?

Comment: The problem seems to have disappeared, so perhaps it was a one time thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have the same problem and never found an ideal fix. You can put a breakpoint on the line of code immediately after the Open command or right-click the line of code and select "run to here".