# Excel 2016 VBA Workbooks.Open Loses Debug Step Mode.. revisited

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, office-2016

Similar to a previous thread*, when I step into a VBA sub in Excel 2016 and then step into the statement:

Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\file2"

the file opens okay but on return the remainder of the sub just executes to the end (I lose step into mode).

I’m running Windows 10 on a 64 bit machine, and a 32 bit version of Office professional Plus 2016

*The same issue is described in following link: 
[Excel 2013 VBA Workbooks.Open Loses Debug Step Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330920/excel-2013-vba-workbooks-open-loses-debug-step-mode)
but the 'ideal' solution is to add a breakpoint after the workbooks.open line.This does not work in Excel 2016 - the routine stops but on the first press of F8 the routine completes to end.

The same issue is describe here:

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/09/04/excel-vba-problem-with-step-into-f8/
but the solution (requiring changes to the registry) applies to earlier versions of Excel and does not work for Windows 10/Office 2016.

This is a frustrating issue preventing effective debugging. Microsoft Pro support have directed me to the Excel fora. So here we are.. :)

Any ideas to fix warmly welcomed.

Comment: Assuming STOP doesn't work after the open if break doesn't?

Comment: Are you sure the script is completing to the end? Could it be that its erroring out with a message? How about placing MsgBox in the subsequent parts to confirm its running to the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced the problem you have described, and for me the following worked:

1) rather than `Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\file2"`  use variables such as:

```
Dim wk as Workbook, sh as worksheet, path as string
path = "C:\file2"
Set wk = Workbooks.Open(path)
Set sh = ActiveSheet
'etc...
```

This allows you to put break points before and after the line which opens the file and that way you can step through the code again.  There's something about doing file input/output lines that causes Excel macros to just run the code rather than stepping after those lines. Also, assigning variable is a good practice since it allows you to troubleshoot problems in the code. But be aware that with several workbooks open you need to keep track of which is which -- so it's also a good idea to assign a variable to `ThisWorkbook` (the one where the code is). Finally, if you use `ActiveSheet` as I show above and you are in the midst of debugging, then whatever sheet is active will be the `ActiveSheet` -- which can be confusing. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Adding breakpoints (and `stop` as an alternative) after the workbook.open line did work - the full code I was testing it on (I say rather sheepishly) had a `Do Loop` in it which had another workbook.open line in it causing the code to run away again. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. The VBA 'macro' sub worked properly in Excel alone, but if called from Access, the routine skipped past the important part of the Excel VBA and the whole procedure failed.
I created a new code module in Excel, pasted the exact same vba code in that module but gave the Sub a new name.

I then called the routine from Access but using the new Excel VBA sub name , and it worked fine. Somehow the old module got corrupted I think.

Comment: I had this problem too, both with SaveAs and Open, and the fix that worked for me was similar. Save the source code out of the offending module, delete the module, save the file, exit, reopen the file, re-create the module (keeping the same name worked OK), paste the text back in, recompile, save, exit. When I went back in, breakpoint mode worked properly. So yes, almost certainly a corruption - probably in the wake of my network problems yesterday.